# How to depend on specific class or package in another Gradle module?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have two gradle modules, `:app` and `:backend`. The backend contains *some* classes that I need in `:app`. So normally I would add `compile project(':backend')` to my app module's dependencies.

However, this adds **all** of backend and its dependencies to `:app`. Is there any way to tell gradle to add *only specific classes or packages (and their dependencies)* from `:backend` to `:app`?

EDIT: `:backend` is a AppEngine module, which contains a whole host of duplicate google dependencies that clash with my android app when I don't use the `android-endpoints` configuration.

Comment: Are these dependencies separate from your endpoints dependencies? For any other dependencies wouldn't a shared library/subproject make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

For removing all the transitive dependencies you can

```
compile (project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')) {
  transitive = false
}
```

For ignoring some of them

```
compile (project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')) {
  exclude(group: 'some.group', module: 'some.module')
}
```

Comment: is a group == to a package?

Comment: It's the maven convention for dependencies.
What kind of clashes are you seeing?